# Comments cleanup please!

Tags: support, status-completed

The following question had the OP pollute all the answers with irrelevant comments, which grew into quite a mess with replies:

[What are the most serious injuries that astronauts have suffered while in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/what-are-the-most-serious-injuries-that-astronauts-have-suffered-while-in-orbit/17484?noredirect=1#comment45132_17484)

Could a mod step in and move a good portion of the comments to chat, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Don't forget you can use flags for this.